# Cordova javascript error: has no method startsWith Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, startswith

i've got two devices one with Lollipop and one with Kitekat... the one with Lollipop does not report any error but when i try my application i obtain this error:

```
10-13 16:56:56.126: I/chromium(6322): [INFO:CONSOLE(99)] "Uncaught
TypeError: Object ALIM. IL SOLE DI LOPARDO MARIANGELA has no 
method 'startsWith'", source: file:///android_asset/www/soggetti3.html (99)
```

here is a part of my javascript:

```
 function onDeviceReady() {

        window.rancolor=ranColor();

        var ricerca=localStorage.getItem('testo_ricerca');
        var risultati = JSON.parse(localStorage["risultati"]);

        var ricerca1=ricerca.toString();
        ricerca1=ricerca1.toUpperCase();
        var res_match=[];

        var lll=risultati.length;

        for(var r=0;r<lll;r++){

            var ppp0=risultati[r][1].toString();
            var ppp1=risultati[r][0].toString();
            var ppp2=risultati[r][2].toString();
            var ppp3=risultati[r][3].toString();

            ppp0=ppp0.toUpperCase();
            alert(ppp0);
            alert(ricerca1);
            var check=ppp0.startsWith(ricerca1);

            if(check==true){
                res_match=res_match.concat([[ppp1,ppp0,ppp2,ppp3]]);
            }

        }
        var y=res_match.length;
```

how should i search an array of strings searching the strings that begin with some other string?

Comment: please post some code for soggetti3.html

Comment: see the edits, thank you ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to implement the startWith function is shown below, then you can use startsWith in your code:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
  // see below for better implementation!
  String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
    return this.indexOf(str) === 0;
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks man it works! but i don't understand the fact that for some device startsWith is defined and for Others not...the code was the same!

Comment: Whether startsWith is available will depend on your browser engine... looks like the Android browser didn't implement this in JS but Chrome does see mobile tab here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: Or simply use `str1.indexOf(str2) === 0` instead